# How to show newsletter form in account create page?

Tags: magento2.3, newsletter-subscriber, create-account

We have removed the default newsletter form and created a custom form for newsletter. I can see that it only display in the home page.

How can I show it on account create page?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have done changes at `subscribe.phtml` which is related to the footer.

But the same files do not call at my Account section it manages from this view files

- `Magento_Customer::form/newsletter.phtml`
- `newsletter_manage_index.xml`
- `Magento\Customer\Block\Newsletter`

So, you want to remove the default newsletter form and created a custom form for newsletter.then you have to work on this page.